# Trying to create an error log ofstream -- getting "one or more multiply defined symbols found"

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do this:

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

static std::ofstream ErrorLog;

void InitErrorLog(std::string FileName) {
    ErrorLog.open(FileName);
}
```

but am getting a "One or more multiply defined symbols found" error when #include-ing in multiple CPP files. What is the STL doing (to provide cout, cin, cerr, etc. -- this approach originates as an alternative to redirecting cerr) that I'm not?

Comment: No need to edit your post to include a "resolution" text.  Simply accept the best answer.  That's indication enough on SO.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid giving 'karma' to people offering insulting answers. The second is less bad than the first, so I'll settle for that one.

Comment: If you're unsatisfied with the answers, you don't need to accept them.  Post comments on the answers you think could be better, and explain to them why you're unsatisfied.

Comment: In what way was @K-ballo's answer "insulting"?  IMO you've accepted the wrong one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're breaking the **one definition rule**. You need to make the method `inline`.

```
inline void InitErrorLog(std::string FileName) {
    ErrorLog.open(FileName);
}
```

Also, note that by declaring your variable `static`, you'll have a copy per translation unit - i.e. it's not a global. To make it global, you need to declare it `extern` in the header and define it in a single implementation file.

Comment: It's the second point I was asking about, much more than the first; I should probably have deleted the function from what I was trying to do before posting, to avoid calling excess attention to it.

Answer (score 4):

You are providing the *definition* for `ErrorLog` in a *header file*. Instead, *define* it in a *source file* and leave an *extern declaration* at the header.

source

```
std::ofstream ErrorLog;

void InitErrorLog(std::string FileName) {
    ErrorLog.open(FileName);
}
```

header

```
extern std::ofstream ErrorLog;

void InitErrorLog(std::string FileName);
```

Additionaly, in order to keep your function at the header you have to make it `inline`.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore: Wouldn't a `static` stream result in a different instance for each translation unit anyway?

Comment: This is better now, because `ErrorLog` *should* be `extern`, not `static`